# Copying mysql table with ENUM fields

Tags: mysql, select, insert, enums, copy

I try to copy a whole table from one mysql database to another. This almost works with

```
INSERT INTO `new-db`.`table` 
    SELECT * FROM `old-db`.`table`;
```

However, ENUM fields are not correctly transferred - they are always empty.

But running

```
INSERT INTO `new-db`.`table` (an_enum_field) 
    SELECT an_enum_field FROM `old-db`.`table`;
```

works correctly.

Is there anything I can do to copy ENUM fields correctly with the first statement ?

Comment: Does it work correctly if you explicitly name every column instead of `SELECT *`? (your second successful example implies it might)

Comment: Yes naming every column explicitly works correctly. Just tried it.

Comment: What about `CREATE TABLE newdb.newtable SELECT * FROM olddb.oldtable`?

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the table structures -- are you certain they are identical (i.e. same column order, same column types, etc.)?

Comment: Got it. The column definitions were the same but the order was different. This caused that problem.

Naming each column in the insert and select statement helps out.

Answer (score 0):

Column order between both tables needs to be the same.
Otherwise the magic statement with * can't correctly map the values.

Naming all columns explicitly helps out (second example from question).